# Shares Not working

Tags: windows-server-2012, network-share, server-message-block

I'm running a ms server 2012 box acting as a file server,

I've set up 4 shares  (IT SECURITY PUBLIC HR) to start out with

each share has its corresponding group as full permissions to the folder

however

when I access the server \server\it  it says i don't have permissions. 
Public has NTLM AUTH as its full read/write and i can't even get into that

Clearly im doing something wrong but im very new to windows server and im not sure how to start trouble shooting.

Comment: There's two "layers" to the security model.  As well as enabling a share, edit the security settings on the folders so that the groups you specified have appropriate permissions.  Right click on folder -> Properties -> security -> edit.

Comment: Check both your Share permissions and NTFS permissions, as suggested.

Answer (score 1):

As the commenters above said, there are two layers of security on Shares.  There's the share level:

[image]

And the NTFS level:

[image]

Make sure the permissions in both places are set to what you expect.

Comment: A follow-up on the share permissions: There's _usually_ no point in using anything but "Full Access" for "Everyone" on the share permissions if you are setting up the NTFS permissions correctly.